# How can I check if all changes are merged with Azure Devops Api?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Using Azure Devops Api I need to check whether for given Pull Request all changes have been already merged into the target branch.

I can retrieve this info via browser:
[image]
Please take note that the conflict info may be outdated due to [Microsoft's approach to PRs](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/pr-diff-is-not-working-correctly/1073023#T-N1073418).

I can't find an answer to this question within json data from Devops Api.

Anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 0):

If a PR have completed merging changes to the target branch, normally there is a new commit generated to the target branch with the commit message like as the format "**`Merged PR {PR Number}: {PR Title}`**" by default. You can find it from the commit history of target branch.

[image]

Then you can use the Azure DevOps REST API "[**Commits - Get Changes**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-changes?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)" to get all the changes for the new commit on the target branch. They also are all the changes merged from the PR.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this should be done via request to [PullRequestCommits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) API. If the answer is empty, then there are no changes to merge in this particular pull request.